# Undefined offset: 70 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dec\function.php on line 10

Tags: php, json, regex

The results are not fetched completely from NewsApi.I am new to PHP.
Please help me get all list from NewsApi.
Here is my code    `

```
<?php
$urlsources=file_get_contents("https://newsapi.org/v1/sources");
$urlsourcearray = json_decode($urlsources,true);
$sources=$urlsourcearray['sources'];

for($i=0;$i<=count($sources);$i++){
  $sites = $urlsourcearray['sources'][$i];
  echo $sites['url'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Using `<=` will exceed the possible range of indices of an array (`[0 - (len - 1)]`). You should be using `$i < count($sources)`, first off.

Comment: You should declare `count($sources)` outside of the for loop, as a variable. Then use that variable in the loop `$i < $countOfSources`. If you use `count()` inside the loop as you currently are, you will be calling `count()` on every single iteration, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this using `<` instead of `<=` because you started from index `0`, Also don't use array `length` count inside `for` loop. *It's a bad practice to use array length's count inside loops.*

```
$urlsources=file_get_contents("https://newsapi.org/v1/sources");
$urlsourcearray = json_decode($urlsources,true);
$sources=$urlsourcearray['sources'];
$count = count($sources); //check out this line
for($i=0;$i<$count; $i++){
  $sites = $urlsourcearray['sources'][$i];
  echo $sites['url'];
}
```

Comment: Nice! Have this, for declaring `$count` outside of the loop :)

Comment: @INTRATUBE sorry I didn't understood it. which button? do you want to use this `$site['url']` values inside any anchor/button link src ?

Comment: @BeingSunny,I want button src link?

Comment: see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link this will help u

Comment: Yes,got it.@BeingSunny

Comment: @INTRATUBE glad you got it, by the way you can accept my answer by ticking..:)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is `<=` when it should just be `<`.

```
for($i=0;$i < count($sources);$i++){
 $sites = $urlsourcearray['sources'][$i];
 echo $sites['url'];
}
```

Arrays are zero-indexed. So if you have an array has 4 items, the indexes would be 0,1,2 and 3.

Comment: You should declare `count($sources)` outside of the for loop, as a variable. Then use that variable in the loop `$i < $countOfSources`. If you use `count()` inside the loop as you currently are, you will be calling `count()` on every single iteration, which is inefficient. Consider if the array had 100 items in it, you would literally call the `count()` function 100 times by the time it finished, instead of just once if you declare it seperately.